# non-text type collaboration by GIT version control (?)

Tags: git, version-control

For version control, GIT is a great tool.
And I find the GIT records the difference of text files.

But if the file is in non-text type, and need to co-work with many members,
is GIT suitable still? (such as picture/image/office docx,xlsx,pptx)
If not, is there more suitable version control tool for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, 

you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have 

similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Git is not good at version control for binary files (like picture, docx, xlsx etc).

And [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (Large File Storage) is usually used to version control for the large files or binary files.

> The core Git LFS idea is that instead of writing large blobs to a Git
>   repository, only a pointer file is written. The blobs are written to a
>   separate server using the Git LFS HTTP API. The API endpoint can be
>   configured based on the remote which allows multiple Git LFS servers
>   to be used.

Also there are other VCS can version control binary files which you can refer [Storing large binary files in git repositories](http://blog.deveo.com/storing-large-binary-files-in-git-repositories/).

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that storing these files in git is fine, in the sense that nothing will be lost or damaged. However, git can't really be used to compare changes, as it would have to have an understanding of each binary format as well as a means of visualizing the differences.

I don't know if such tools exist but I would be impressed if they do. We can't even merge XML or json intelligently, so binaries are a whole other level.

One suggestion for the docx files: maybe you can use markdown format instead, which is text and typically rendered by GitHub and Bitbucket so it's still human friendly.